# Uncountable subset with lower bounded distances has cardinality at least $c$?

Tags: metric-spaces, separable-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a nonseparable metric space. It follows from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/618919/522332) that there exists an uncountable subset $N$ of $X$ and $r>0$ such that for all $x\neq y$ in $N$ we have $d(x,y)>r$.

Is it possible to show that such $N$ must have cardinality greater than or equal to $\mathbb R$?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends upon whether or not you accept the [continuum hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis). If you do, then the statement is automatically true, because then the cardinal of any uncountable is greater than or equal to the cardinal of $\Bbb R$.

Otherwise, take an uncountable set $X$ whose cardinal is smaller than that of $\Bbb R$, consider on it the discrete metric and take $N=X$. Then, if $x,y\in N$ and $x\ne y$, $d(x,y)=1>\frac12$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's embarrassing as I cannot commit on the continum hypothesis being true or false. Can I at least say that the power set $\mathcal{P} (N)$ has cardinality strictly greater than $c$?

Comment: No. They have the *same* cardinal.

Comment: Ok I got this question from here : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4123497/522332 but I must be missing the point of the argument. Would you mind to have a look? Thanks a lot.